# Why RemoveAll don't remove specific elements from list?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, removeall

RemoveAll method don't work when I try to remove all elements. After removing I try to Console.WriteLine() all elements from mainArray using foreach loop. Why this way of removing specific elements from the list don't work and maybe there is better way?

```
        var mainArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 1 , 2, 3  };

        mainArray.ToList().RemoveAll(n => n == 1);
```

Comment: Hint, look at the return type of `ToList()`. Notice how it's not `void`.

Comment: Read your code. You start with `mainArray` and copy it into a new List with the call to `ToList`. Then you call `RemoveAll` and remove the elements numbered one in that list, emptying the list. You don't assign that partially emptied list to any variable. At the end of that statement, you have a reduced list about to go out of scope and the original array, untouched

Answer (score 1):

> Why RemoveAll don't remove specific elements from list?

Short answer: it does.

Long answer:
You started with an array. If you hover your mouse over the  `.ToList()` method, you can see the return type. No surprise it is a `List<Int32>`. A different object, in a different place in your memory. You are removing the elements from the List, and not from the array.

```
var mainArray = new Int32[] { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 };
var list = mainArray.ToList();
list.RemoveAll(n => n == 1);
mainArray = list.ToArray();
```